# Using puppeteer to get used CSS @media rules

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

I've written a little node app that will scrape a website for its used CSS using [puppeteer](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/puppeteer/) and Headless Chrome.

It works great, apart from one thing: It doesn't get grab `@media` rules?

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const util = require('util');
const fs = require("fs");

(async () => {
 const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
 const page = await browser.newPage();
 await page.coverage.startCSSCoverage();
 await page.goto('http://localhost');
 await page.setViewport({width  : 320, height : 640});
 const css_coverage = await page.coverage.stopCSSCoverage();
 console.log(util.inspect(css_coverage, { showHidden: false, depth: null }));
 await browser.close();

let final_css_bytes = '';
let total_bytes = 0;
let used_bytes = 0;

for (const entry of css_coverage) {
  final_css_bytes = "";

  total_bytes += entry.text.length;
  for (const range of entry.ranges) {
    used_bytes += range.end - range.start - 1;
    final_css_bytes += entry.text.slice(range.start, range.end) + '\n';
  }

  filename = entry.url.split('/').pop();

  fs.writeFile('./'+filename, final_css_bytes, error => {
    if (error) {
      console.log('Error creating file:', error);
    } else {
      console.log('File saved');
    }
  });
}
})();
```

Does anyone have any idea why `@media` rules are not included in the final output, when the page has lots of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reported this as a bug in Chrome, and it's been moved to Chromium:

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=983887

Hopefully one day soon this feature will be added.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is the behavior with chromium itself. If you checked chrome dev tool's code coverage, the used css would not contain the definitions for media-queries. Only the actual selectors will be available.

The same applies for font-faces and keyframes. There is even an [issue in chromium](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=929105) for font-face.

To extract out the css used in a page, you can check out something like [minimalcss](https://github.com/peterbe/minimalcss)